# Magento : Catalog Price Rules "Apply Rules" Programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, price, discount, price-rules

i'm create Catalog Price Rules Programmatically it's work fine.

The issue is, I need to login with admin and click button **"Apply Rules"** other wise discount is not apply in magento store. So I need "Apply Rules" programmatically and I try bellow code but its not work.

```
try{
  $catalogPriceRule = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule');
  $catalogPriceRule->applyAll();
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e;
}
```

[image]

**Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.**

Answer (score 0):

Use this for particular rule

$rule = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->load(1);

```
    $rule->save(); //save the rule

    $rule->applyAll(); //apply all the rules
```

And for all rules

$rule = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule');

```
    $rule->save(); //save the rule

    $rule->applyAll(); //apply all the rules
```